# PHP - How to do a string replace in a very large number of files?

Tags: php, sed, server

I have two million text files in a server online accesible to internet users. I was asked to make a change (a string replace operation) to these files as soon as possible. I was thinking about doing a `str_replace` on every text file on the server. However, I don't want to tie up the server and make it unreachable by internet users.

Do you think the following is a good idea?

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);


$path=realpath('/dir/');
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
   set_time_limit(100);
  //do str_replace stuff on the file
}
```

Comment: "two million text files in a server" - wut.

Comment: figure out how to do 2 and the rest will follow, *just like sheep*

Comment: Why would this make the server unreachable? It should be able to run multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: This does not sound like a job for PHP, but rather `find` and `sed`. http://superuser.com/search?q=replace+multiple+files+sed  Something along these lines: http://superuser.com/questions/146389/how-to-replace-every-text-in-a-mac-folder/146392#146392

Comment: @user2070775 I guess you don't want your server hang after a couple of minutes, right ?  read my answer, specifically the `xargs` explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find), [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) and [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) from `shell`, i.e.:

```
cd /dir

find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/OLD/NEW/g
```

Will search all files recursively (hidden also) inside the current `dir` and replace `OLD` for `NEW` using `sed`.

---

Why `-print0`?

From [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

> If you  are  piping  the  output  of  find  into another  program and
>   there is the faintest possibility that the files which you are
>   searching for might contain a newline,  then you should seriously
>   consider using the '-print0' option instead of '-print'.

---

Why `xargs` ?

From [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

> The specified command is run once for each matched file.

That is, if there are 2000 files in `/dir`, then `find ... -exec ...` will result in 2000 invocations of `sed`; whereas `find ... | xargs ...` will only invoke `sed` once or twice.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this with PHP, it's most likely to fail horribly and I'll take up all your system resources.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/search/replace/g' {} +
```

The example above with search and replace string and it's recursive and regular files including hidden ones.

Comment: Your answer will make the server hang after a while, you should use `xargs`, read my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a Python program limited to one core (which is the default). If your machine has multiple cores, and at least one is generally free, you should be set.